# How to create header and footer image in my media player?

Tags: android, image, header, footer

I wish to create header and footer image in my media player. Now the media player is working fine for me.

1. If I click media player its display video thumbnails in center of the screen(layout). 
   If I click that thumbnails the video will play.
2. My doubt is how to create header and footer images from video thumbnails showing page.

Give me your suggestion please, I am new with android applications.

Element description;

a. Header image, a stretched background image. The location of this external image comes 
   from the application xml.

b. Footer image, a stretched background image. The location of this external image comes 
   from the application xml.

xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: give me your idea and sample link its very helpful to me....

Comment: You can use layout to combine images and player

Comment: if u dont mine..i am new for android application please give me the some example link....

Comment: Please post your layout xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use LinearLayout for header and footer inside RelativeLayout. Set both LinearLayot's orientation to Horizontal. You can also use DroidDraw. I use it sometime whenever i stuck with android layouts.

Comment: Same time possible to use both layout?

Comment: It is possible to combine layouts in many ways and to use one layout inside other. However, take some time to read more about layouts and understand them better in order to get best solution without combining too many of them, since this leads to inefficient layouts. Here are some more tricks on relative layout: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/

Comment: Yeah! You can use layouts inside other layouts. The first Layout tag mentioned by you in your XML file will be considered as a root tag by Android. You should use RelativeLayout as a root layout and put header and footer LinearLayouts with Horizontal orientation  inside the root layout. If you need more help let me know. And i do agree with dstefanox that you should go through a little bit over layout stuff as it is the most trickiest part of Android.

Comment: thanks its working fine...my last doubt this is static header and footer image..but Dynamic header and footer image is possible or not?

Comment: Cheers if it is working now. Yeah its possible because Android SDK provides Classes for each and every layout element but before messing up with Dynamic Layouts, you just need to dig a little bit more about layouts as sometime layouts could be a headache in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to use RelativeLayout when laying down elements on your application page. Good starting point for this layout is in [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout). Also, this layout allows you to do exactly what you want, using ALIGN_PARENT_TOP and ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM attributes for your images. One more advantage of this layout is that it will easily adjust to any screen size. On the other side, only disadvantage of this layout is that it can be sometimes tricky to fully understand it's behavior.